# Interpreting the data published on /camera_info topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, gazebo-plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [camera plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera) with a robot in gazebo simulator. When I echo the `/camera_info` topic I receive the following data_frame

```
header: 
  seq: 69
  stamp: 
    secs: 1417
    nsecs: 503000000
  frame_id: "leader/camera_link"
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
K: [381.36246688113556, 0.0, 320.5, 0.0, 381.36246688113556, 240.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [381.36246688113556, 0.0, 320.5, -26.69537268167949, 0.0, 381.36246688113556, 240.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
binning_x: 0
binning_y: 0
roi: 
  x_offset: 0
  y_offset: 0
  height: 0
  width: 0
  do_rectify: False
```

In the above frame it appears to me that **P** has the camera matrix (first 9 entries) data. However, the content of **K** also look similar. I couldn't find the explanation of these variables.

**Question:**
What do **K** and **P** values represent in the `/camera_info` topic ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302357/interpreting-the-data-published-on-/camera_info-topic/) by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros documentation for this message has alot of good information that answers your question.

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vvyogi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29579/vvyogi/) on 2018-09-05**:
Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. I googled various keywords but didn't reach this one.